# What are the downsides of an App transfer in Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

If I transfer an app from one account to another in playstore, do I loose all the work done in promoting that app earlier? like ASO, links etc.
I want to evaluate what are the downsides of moving an app from one developer account to another.

Answer (score 0):

I have sold some applications to a different company.

You need not worry. ALl your important stuff is safe. Like, Number of installs, reviews, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Reports are not accessible anymore, you have to download them before (Google warns you about that).

As it is a new developer account, the developer's page of the Play Store is not transferred. So the link to the developer's page is not valid anymore, you have to update that everywhere you linked it (if it's still your app). Writing this here because in my case I had to move the apps (I moved country) and still all apps are mine.

I can't give you an answer about promotion as I didn't any. But I see that my app is still shown on Google search because the store URL of the app remains the same (play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= **yourAppId**).